# When using Vue.js with Vite it is making 400 requests from just one function call

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I don't know if this is a bug with Vite.js or maybe this is normal. But Vite.js is making 400 requests when I use `date-fns`. I only made one function call which resulted in 400 ajax requests being made from date-fns.

This causes the page load to take **2 - 4 seconds** after reload. Am I missing something here?

```
<script>
import { formatWithOptions } from 'date-fns/fp'

export default {
    setup() {
        const dateToString = formatWithOptions({ locale: 'en' }, 'yyyy-mm-dd')
    }
}
</script>
```

Screenshot:
[image]

Comment: You can improve page load by using HTTP2. With HTTP1, there's some limit to concurrent requests (6 I think), which leads to blocking and this slowness. With HTTP2, all the requests can happen in parallel. Browsers only support HTTP2 with HTTPS, so you'd have to set that up as well. You can either enable https with Vite or use a reverse proxy like Nginx. Enabling https on vite was pretty straightforward and had a huge impact on the load time.

Answer (score 1):

It's a Vite ***dev*** server. It might be absolutely normal.

Try to build your app for productions with `npm run build` and serve your `./dist` folder with, let's say with [`pm2`](https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/expose/).

Also, pay attention to a bundle size. Not used parts of the library should not be included in the bundle.

Comment: When it is built for production then its all normal.

Comment: Well, then that's okay. You can't see this behavior with `webpack` because it transfers everything via WebSocket connection. And there is a lot of messages flying around as well. If your bundle size for prod is fine - then everything should be fine.

Comment: I can only recommend to not look at `All` tab in the network, and use `XHR` instead. :)

Comment: these are ALL XHR requests.

Comment: this is actually very strange. what version of `date-fns` do you use?